# Youtube API V3 404 Error On Onsen APP

Tags: cordova, youtube, onsen-ui, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I've used ready onsen UI youtube app from: https://github.com/frandiox/OnsenUI-YouTube

on the local server, its working fine but I've created the build using Cordova than getting error of 404

[image]